# JQuery: append div with class that is a var

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-append

I have a line that appends a new div to an existing one. However I also want to add a class to the new div. The class's name is actually held in a var.

I am just unsure of the syntax of this - could anyone point me in the right direction at all?

```
 var itemclass = "myclass";

 $('#wrapper').append('<div class="itemclass"></div>');
```

So far I have tried:

```
 $('#wrapper').append('<div class=" . itemclass . "></div>');

 $('#wrapper').append('<div class=" & itemclass & "></div>');
```

To no effect... any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are concatenating a string, it is done like:

```
$('#wrapper').append('<div class="' + itemclass + '"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

JS uses + to concatenate items, like this:

```
 $('#wrapper').append('<div class="' + itemclass + '"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

concatenation is the + sign in javascript, not a period like in PHP